# How do I extract a particular sentence from a string using NSRange?

Tags: ios, string, swift, swift2, nsrange

This is my code:

```
regex.enumerateMatchesInString(parsingMemo.string, options: NSMatchingOptions(rawValue: 0), range: NSMakeRange(0, parsingMemo.length), usingBlock: { (match: NSTextCheckingResult?,_, _) -> Void in
let trange = match!.rangeAtIndex(0)
let range = Range(start: trange.location, end: trange.length)
var insideString: String = parsingMemo.string.substringWithRange(NSMakeRange(trange.location,trange.length)
```

The code gives me the following error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'NSRange' (aka '_NSRange') to expected argument type 'Range' (aka 'Range')

How can I fix my code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the `NSRange` that you were given into a Swift `Range`. Something like this should work:

```
let start = parsingMemo.string.characters.startIndex.advancedBy(trange.location)
let end = start.advancedBy(trange.length)

var insideString: String = parsingMemo.string.substringWithRange(start..<end)
```

Comment: You can also use subscript `parsingMemo.string[start..<end]`